# Best way to concurrently lookup a dictionary?

Tags: python, multithreading, dictionary, multiprocessing

Sorry if this question seems overly noob to you. I've taken programming courses but never one on computer architecture. I had to pretty much learn from Wiki/SO/Google.

I have a `dict` called `LUT`, and I need to parallelize its lookup (READ-ONLY). I have a `list` of `item`s that I am scattering to multiple threads/processes, and each thread/process will then lookup `LUT[item]` for each `item` in its respective chopped-up list.

I can only think of 7 options to achieve this:

`1`. `multithreading` module, all threads lookup the same `dict`

`2`. `multiprocessing` module, all processes lookup the same `dict`

`3`. `multiprocessing` module, all processes lookup their own copy of `dict`, e.g. if there are 2 processes, there are 2 copies of the `dict`

`4`. `multiprocessing` module, all processes lookup a "shared proxy dict": `Manager.dict`

The following 3 options use `Cython` since I've heard it can be used to overcome Python's GIL.

`5`. Cython & C++'s STL `unordered_map` and `multithreading`, all threads lookup the same `unordered_map`

`6`. Cython & C++'s STL `unordered_map` and `multiprocessing`, all processes lookup the same `unordered_map`

`7`. Cython & C++'s STL `unordered_map` and `multiprocessing`, all processes lookup their respective copy of the `unordered_map`

I have already tried options `2, 3, & 4`. `2 & 4` are around 100-1000x slower than serial lookup. Option `3` works well, but its memory usage is too high, since it makes use of multiple copies of the dictionary.

Options `5, 6, & 7` use `Cython` and its ability to extend with C++'s STL `unordered_map`, which is the C++-equivalent of Python's `dict`. Option `5` should technically overcome Python's GIL, but I am wondering if multithreading can really solve something that is CPU-bound. What is my best bet here?

Comment: this makes no sense ... dicts have a lookup of O(1)  ... why would you parellize it ...

Comment: I want to concurrently look up one dict. For example, I have a list of 10,000 items. Instead of serially looking up each item one at a time, I can parallelize it and look it up 2 at a time.

Comment: Oh I see ... hmmm I would recommend sending copies of the dictionary so that each thread has its own copy ... shared memory access tends to be pricey and almost certainly negates any speed gain unless your list is much much larger(maybe even then) ... this problem may be better suited to something like GO

Comment: If your dict being looked up is big, you could try using a NoSQL database like MongoDB.

Comment: shared memory is expensive and slow ... thats all there is too it ...  one option maybe to store your dict in a postgres database ... that each thread creates a connection to (pretty sure postgres has pretty good concurrency support)

Comment: @kroolik that maybe easier than my suggestion of postgres ... but really probably any database program is roughly equivelent in terms of success for this particular task  (I think they all support concurrent reading)

Comment: @JoranBeasley Thanks for your input, but can a thread utilize more than one core? [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4496680/python-threads-all-executing-on-a-single-core) says that all threads execute on one logical core because of Python's GIL. Hence I should use `unordered_map` to avoid the GIL?

Comment: @JoranBeasley, more or less, yeah. The part where MongoDB might be better for this use case than postgres is that it's schemaless so you can put literally any json in a single collection, and it's native data format is JSON itself. On the other hand. PostgreSQL has something similar called [hstore](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/hstore.html) used for key/value storage.

Comment: I suppose I should look into SQL/NoSQL; I am just afraid lookup will now be IO bound

Comment: Alternatively you can use [memcached](http://memcached.org/) or [redis](http://redis.io/). Both are in-memory key/value storages.

Comment: MultiThreading (in Python) won't help with something that is CPU-bound, only IO-bound. MultiProcessing sounds like overkill for a dictionary lookup. You know [premature optimization is the root of all evil](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization), right?

Comment: Thanks everyone, I've learned immensely

Comment: If you only lookup a value once and you do not need pairs of values you can use `multiprocessing.Pool.map`. Could you explain more of how you need the values?

Comment: @User, the dictionary is actually an in-memory inverse-index `(word->doc-number)` i.e. if I have a query sentence, I can lookup all documents that contain any word within that sentence. Since I have 1000000s of sentences to query, I would like to split it up among my cores.

Comment: I plan to use `multiprocessing` as per @JoranBeasley, and to circumvent the memory issue, I'll just offload the actual documents into an HDF5/PyTables `table`, which is out-of-core storage, supports numeric data (since my documents are tfidf'ed), allows indexing, and allows concurrent READ-ONLY threads. I need an embedded datastore, hence aforementioned SQl/NoSQL wont be much of a help..

Comment: 5 should be your best bet. Lookup is CPU-bound... per core. If you have multiple cores, multithreading will work faster than a single thread. (Assuming IO and synchronization at a higher level isn't a problem.)