# Writing to text widget during runtime using Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I used Tkinter to create a simple UI for my python script. It's quite a long program and once the user clicks on a button, it takes at least 5 mins to finally create the output Excel sheet. In the meanwhile, I want to use the text widget to keep the user informed of the status. But when I use `text.insert(index,'Fetching rates...\n')` everytime, the text widget gets validated only when the whole execution completes and the cursor remainis in sandclock mode the whole time. Please help out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As like most GUI systems, **Tkinter** is basically a single threaded system.So,when the operation begins in Excel sheet,your GUI stops responding.Try using `update_idletasks()` if you want to force the GUI to show the text.

For more details,visit [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4496918/2276527)

Comment: you are welcome buddy ;). You should try the make the whole UI responsive though

Comment: I'm a newbie. Could you elaborate?

Comment: What i'm trying to say is you should try to use root.update_idletasks or frame.update... or canvas.update... or whatever it is you are using so that your whole UI is responsive & not just the text area

Comment: hey, why does the application go gray (title bar says 'Not Responding') when I click anywhere on the window when idletasks is doing its job?

Comment: that means your `update_idletasks` is not doing its job properly,which means you haven't used it well. Like i said yesterday,don't use it with a widget,but with the root or frame or canvas.

Comment: You have to use that code where it is creating excel sheet,so that it gets called multiple times

Comment: Same problem with root.idletasks(). I am using it immediately after every text.insert()

Comment: `root.update_idletasks`. Not after every `text.insert`. You must be running some loop for writing data to excel sheet.Include `update_idletasks` there,so that every time some data is written,the next thing it would run is `upate_idletasks`