# Python, Tkinter, Subprocess- getting stdout and inserting it to Text

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, popen, ttk

Have mercy, I'm a beginner.

I'm trying to write a very basic application to run 'chkdsk c:' and print out the output to a text box line by line. for each line I want a ttk.Progressbar to move a bit. I've seen similar questions answered here, but couldn't get them to work. I got this far:

```
from Tkinter import *
import ttk
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

gui = Tk()

text = Text(gui)
lb = ttk.Label(text="Chkdsk")
prog = ttk.Progressbar(mode='indeterminate')

def chkdsk():
    proc = Popen(['chkdsk','c:'],stdout=PIPE)
    while True:
        line = proc.stdout.readline()
        if line != '':
            text.insert(INSERT, "\n")
            text.insert(END, line.rstrip())
            prog.step(1)
            gui.update()
        else:
            break

bt = ttk.Button(text="Chkdsk", command=chkdsk).grid(row=4, column=5)

text.grid(row=6, column= 5)
lb.grid(row=3, column=5)
prog.grid(row=7,column=5)
mainloop()
```

Ok, so when I run this .pyw script on an **elevated command prompt(this is good for my purposes)** - "python chkdsk.pyw" and initiate the chkdsk, it starts working, and then shortly thereafter becomes non responding.

I believe the problem has something to do with buffering?

Comment: [see links in this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22627148/tkinter-subprocess-locking-gui-and-not-returning-stdout-to-text#comment34460372_22627148)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Thanks, I can easily change one line to make that work. but I can't understand 90% of it.

Comment: If you have a specific question about the code; [ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`readline` is blocking. Use non-blocking `read` and the `after`-method.