# Can I/O operations be parallel in Python's ThreadPoolExecutor?

Tags: python

In CPython, GIL doesn't let Python code run in parallel threads but GIL is released when I/O operation is performed.

Say there are several relatively lengthy I/O operations: dump some raw data to file, create log file entry and perform Postgres query. If I run all of them via ThreadPoolExecutor, will they run in parallel?

Are my initial assumptions correct?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29270818/why-is-a-python-i-o-bound-task-not-blocked-by-the-gil might help

Comment: @Ilja Indeed, that's what I was asking for. Don't know why I haven't found it before. Thanks.