# Google Cloud Compute engine CPU usage shows 100% but dashboard only shows 10% usage

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I am running a multiprocessing program and i expect the CPU usage to be close to 100%. It did show 100% when i run `top` command
[image]

However, the dashboard seem only shows 10% usage
[image]

My Machine Setup is as follow:

[image]

I am curious whether this is the problem of google cloud? or i am misunderstanding some concept?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the `top` output on a particular process row the 100% refers to a single CPU core (as seen by the OS), not all of them. If you press the <kbd>1</kbd> key `top` will also display the per-core CPU usage, you'll see only one core being actually at/close to 100% busy.

Since you have 8 cores on your instance your overall usage would be 100% / 8 = 12.5% - pretty much inline with the graph.

Maybe relevant - assuming the python process you're showing in the `top` output is the one you're interested in you should know it can't run on multiple cores, see [Python threads all executing on a single core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4496680/python-threads-all-executing-on-a-single-core).

So if you're expecting to bump your CPU usage you'd have to split your python application into multiple processes, not threads.