# GCE shows only ~15% usage but top shows ~99%

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I was running a load test but seeing only ~20% CPU on GCE. That was surprising, so I decided to SSH into my machine and run `top`, which showed me 99.7% utilization.

I found a question that was very similar: [Google Cloud Compute engine CPU usage shows 100% but dashboard only shows 10% usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53346844/google-cloud-compute-engine-cpu-usage-shows-100-but-dashboard-only-shows-10-us)

However, I am certain I only have one core (1 vCPU, 3.75 GB memory).

Here's top running that shows 99.7% utilization:

[image: top]

What could be the reason for this?

Comment: The low load average suggests that your job hasn't been using 100% CPU consistently or for very long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even for a single core case, when workload is not split between several cores, the curve shape and the Y-coordinate of the CPU Utilization chart depend on the aggregation and alignment settings you use: for instance `max` or `mean`, `1m` or `1h` alignment period, etc. For instance in case of a short peak load, the wide time window will act as a big denominator for the mean aligner. That way you'll get lower values on the chart.

For more details please see:

[Google Monitoring > Documentation > Alignment](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/charts/metrics-selector#alignment)

[Google Cloud Blog > Stackdriver tips and tricks: Understanding metrics and building charts](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/management-tools/stackdriver-tips-and-tricks-understanding-metrics-and-building-charts)